# TS2339 Property myProperty does not exist on type SetStateAction<User>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, setstate

I'm trying to use TypeScript in React and getting an error I don't understand:

```
<html>TS2339: Property 'subEnd' does not exist on type 'SetStateAction&lt;User&gt;'.<br/>Property 'subEnd' does not exist on type '(prevState: User) =&gt; User'.
```

I'm trying to use `this` in a method for an object I am setting with `useState`, and am getting an error:

```
function fetchUserInfo(
  data: InterfaceJsonUserInfo,
  setUserObject: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<User>>
) {
  setUserObject({
    id: data.id,
    subEnd: new Date(data.subEnd),
    subExpired() {
      const subEndDate = this.subEnd;
      const nowDate = new Date();
      return (subEndDate > nowDate);
    },
  }
```

And here's my interface:

```
export interface User {
  id: string, // Uuid
  subEnd: Date,
  subExpired: () => boolean,
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error because `subEnd` is on the User interface.

When I change from `<User>` to  `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>`, the code actually works, but I want to specify the type instead of using `any`.  So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the `this` is a `User` when calling `subExpired`:

```
export interface User {
  id: string, // Uuid
  subEnd: Date,
  subExpired: (this: User) => boolean,
}
```